# Hide taskbar using Python in Windows XP

Tags: python

Is there a way to hide the Windows taskbar using Python? If not- is there a way to disable or to re-size and lock it using the registry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft support document [KB186119](http://web.archive.org/web/20140814062336/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/186119) demonstrates how to hide the taskbar using Visual Basic. Here's a ctypes version for Python, but using `ShowWindow` instead of `SetWindowPos`:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL("user32")

SW_HIDE = 0
SW_SHOW = 5

user32.FindWindowW.restype = wintypes.HWND
user32.FindWindowW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # lpClassName
    wintypes.LPCWSTR) # lpWindowName

user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HWND, # hWnd
    ctypes.c_int)  # nCmdShow

def hide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)

def unhide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)
```

Comment: The most beautiful thing about this code is that it continues to work up to Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a possibility to also hide the start button? Right now it still stays.

Comment: @Henrik, for older versions of Windows, try finding the start button or orb using FindWindowEx, as I did in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16651313/205580). To clarify, in Windows 10 hiding the taskbar also hides the start button.

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate it. works prefectly on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @eryksun answer, if you try this in windows 7 you would still get to see the start button... I did i little tweek in his code to

1) Hide the start button (with the `hWnd_btn_start = user32.FindWindowW(u"Button", 'Start')` )

2) Now you can pass Hide (default behaviour) or Show to the command line to show or hide the taskbar.

```
import ctypes
import sys

from ctypes import wintypes

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL("user32")

SW_HIDE = 0
SW_SHOW = 5

HIDE = True;

for idx,item in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print(idx, item);
    if (idx == 1 and item.upper() == 'SHOW'):
        HIDE = False;

#HIDE = sys.argv[1] = 'HIDE' ? True : False;


user32.FindWindowW.restype = wintypes.HWND
user32.FindWindowW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # lpClassName
    wintypes.LPCWSTR) # lpWindowName

user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HWND, # hWnd
    ctypes.c_int)  # nCmdShow

def hide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)

    hWnd_btn_start = user32.FindWindowW(u"Button", 'Start')
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd_btn_start, SW_HIDE)

def unhide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)

if (HIDE):
    hide_taskbar();
else:
    unhide_taskbar();
```

Usage: 
To show the taskbar `python hideTaskBar.py Show`
To hide the taskbar `python hideTaskBar.py Hide`

Again, many thanks to @eryksun